# Pricing Knock Out Barrier Options by solving Black Scholes PDE (MATLAB)

Tags: black-scholes, programming, black-scholes-pde, finite-difference-method, barrier

> **This question is based on MATLAB functions**.

Suppose there is a stock S following the process

### $dS_t=(r-q)S_tdt+\sigma(S_t,t)dW_t$

r - risk-free rate, q - dividend yield, W - Weiner process

The Local Volatility Surface has been given

### $\sigma(S,t)=0.25.e^{-t}(100/S)^\alpha$

Option Price $V(S,t)$ being given as

### $\frac{\delta V}{\delta t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\delta^{2}V}{\delta S^{2}}\sigma(S,t)^{2}S^{2}+(r-q)S\frac{\delta V}{\delta S}-rV=0$

We are supposed to use Explicit, Implicit and Crank-Nicholson Finite Difference schemes *respectively* to solve for the option price. However, as you can see, this is a barrier call option.

The barrier being B = £130.

$S_0=$ £ 100, $K=$ £ 100, $r=$ 3% i.e the risk-free-rate

$q=$ 5% the dividend yield, time to maturity $T=$ 0.5, $\alpha$ in the local volatility function = 0.35

The pay-off function is given as

## $h_{up-and-out{call}}(S_T)= max(S_T-K,0),\; if \;max_{0\leq{t}\leq{T}}S_t<B$.

### {0 in other cases}

**My attempt**

> I present my thought process here. I already have the Matlab code related to solving European Call option using the above three iteration methods described. In summary, I am unable to code the barrier option. I provide a picture below what I am aiming for.

[image: A sample Barrier Option with £ 75 being the maximum barrier, you can see how the option price cease to exist once the barrier is crossed]

1. The stock price is a random variable varying with time, the maturity date for options is 0.5; i.e $t\in[0,0.5]$
2. It is easier to solve when the $\sigma$ is a fixed value, here being a r.v. has made it difficult.
3. I have tried adding the if-else condition to a usual European Call pricing code, however it is giving me back error.
4. We need to modify the boundary condition to fit to that of barrier option (maybe)

I tried adding the following piece of code to the script below in link.

```
if S<=B 
    Vold = max(S-K,0) 
else 
    Vold = 0 
end
```

I am uploading a sample code for pricing european call.
[Click here to access the code](https://github.com/Raanaji/MATLAB-Files/blob/master/ExplicitSchemeForEuropeanCall.m)

Since the question is bigger than what can be explained here, I would like to discuss it with the community first and then move forward with discussion.

**Thank You**